# How do I change what variable gets changed when the brightness control is triggered?

Tags: nvidia, keyboard, laptop, brightness, backlight

I am facing a problem, I am not able to change the brightness on my dell G15 5515. Though the brightness control GUI shows up and reacts to brightness up and down key, it doesn't do anything.

But, I believe I have discovered a part of the solution. I have discovered that in the path `/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl0` there is a file named `brightness` , when I change the value in this file by using nano editor with sudo priveledge, the brightness change is instant, so I assume that the brightness file is a variable.

However there also exist another path adjacent to previous one `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_wmi_ec_backlight` and in there too there is a file named `brightness` and this file's value *does* change when I press the brightness control key up and down!

So , help me figure out how I force the brightnes control to change the value of `brightness` file inside the `amd` directory rather than in the `nvidia` directory.

You're help will be greatly appreciated and will help many lost souls.